# add_executable create two binaries files instead of one

Tags: cmake

protoc.cmake:

```
set(protoc_files
  ${protobuf_source_dir}/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc
)

add_executable(protoc ${protoc_files})
target_link_libraries(protoc libprotobuf libprotoc)
add_executable(protobuf::protoc ALIAS protoc)

set(PROTOC_NAME "protoc")

set_target_properties(protoc PROPERTIES
        VERSION ${protobuf_VERSION}
        OUTPUT_NAME ${PROTOC_NAME})

if(WIN32)
    set(PROTOC_SUFFIX ".exe")
    set_target_properties(protoc PROPERTIES
            SUFFIX ${PROTOC_SUFFIX})
else()
    set(PROTOC_SUFFIX)
endif()

set(PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${PROTOC_NAME}${PROTOC_SUFFIX}" PARENT_SCOPE)
```

I have included source of google protocol buffer compiler to my project, and I use previous cmake file for generating runtime binary, but instead of one file I get two executable files: "protoc" and "protoc-3.6.1".

I am using CLion IDE 2018.1.5 with bundled CMake 3.10.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.

On Windows I don't have a such problem.

Comment: I guess, one of these files is actually a **symlink** to another one. Probably, `protoc` is a symlink to `protoc-3.6.1`. This is what `VERSION` property implies.

Comment: You have two `add_executable` calls.

Comment: [cmake's documetation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/add_executable.html) says that aliased target does not appear in the generated buildsystem as a make target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tsyvarev said in comment, one of these files is actually a symlink to another one. This is what `VERSION` property implies.